# 未翻訳：検索結果が見つからない時の提案

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

適当に「ニワトリ」と入れて検索をかけた所、見つからない時の提案が翻訳されていませんでした。

> Suggestions:
>
> Try fewer keywords.
>   Try different keywords.
>   Try more general keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

大変遅くなってしまいましたが、反映されております。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: その箇所は確認しました。しかし『utau』と検索したところ、『もしかして：』にあたる箇所が翻訳されていませんでした。

Comment: @Laclip 『もしかして：』に変更いたしました！